# React - unable to use `this` to call component methods in callback function

Tags: reactjs, exif-js

I'm fairly new to React and currently working on a project that uses `exif-js` library to read image EXIF data, see sample code below. `EXIF.getData(file, callback)` is the method from this library for reading the given image and performing some other tasks in the callback. In my component, I defined a function (`doSomething`) to be used by the callback. But when I try to call the function `this.doSomething()`, it throws error: `this.doSomething is not a function`.

In their [documentation](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js#usage), they explained that `In the callback function you should use "this" to access the image...`, so it looks like `this` is being used to refer the file inside the callback, that's why there is no such method on the file object.

So question is: how do I call my other functions in the same component, if `this` is referring to something else in the library callback?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EXIF from "exif-js"; // https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js/blob/HEAD/exif.js

export default class QuestionComponent extends Component {

    handleChange = (e) => {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        EXIF.getData(file, function () {
            console.log(this.exifdata);
            this.doSomething(); // <====== fails here
        });
    }

    // how to call this method from the callback function above?
    doSomething () {
        console.log("...");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="file" id="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try binding your `handleChange` function in the component's constructor, i.e. `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-binding-necessary-at-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind `this` of the class to the `doSomething` handler. This can be done in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  ...

  this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
}
```

or more easily defined as an arrow function.

```
doSomething = () => {
  console.log("...");
}
```

Then you can save a reference to the outer `this` of the class component to close over in the callback scope.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const self = this;
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  EXIF.getData(file, function () {
      console.log(this.exifdata);
      self.doSomething();
  });
}
```